# Entity Framework relationship between columns of different types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have an existing database which lets say I can't change. One of the tables in this database has the following structure:

```
Table Foo
FooKey         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
ParentFooKey   VARCHAR(36)
```

So essentially each row can have a relation to its parent in the same table.

I am trying to map this relationship using EF fluent API but having trouble because of the difference in type between the two columns.

I've tried creating a property in my Foo class which simply parses the `ParentFooKey` into a Guid but when I try to use this in Fluent API I get an error because the property isn't mapped in EF.

Alternatively is there a way to map `ParentFooKey` as a Guid in EF? The value in the `ParentFooKey` column is always either the string representation of a GUID or NULL.

Comment: In SQL Foreign key columns should have the same values, so that why EF not allowed you to do this.If you have this problem it's mean that you design your model wrong.
Read little more about foreign keys in SQL .

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that but unfortunately the model is old and I didn't design it. Hence the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i know, you can't.
You'll have to query what you need, something like:

```
YourContext.YourDbSet.Where(x=>x.FooKey == parentKey)
```

Also you can create an Extension method for string to convert it to GUID to make your life easier. Something like that:

```
public Guid ToGuidOrDefault(this string s){
Guid guid = Guid.Empty;
Guid.TryParse(s, out guid){
return guid;

}
```

Comment: I thought this might be the case but wanted to avoid it if possible because this way means making a separate call for each row returned from 1Foo1

Comment: You could type in the join requirement yourself so EF will create the query accordingly. However, I don't think the Guid.Parse call will be translatable into SQL.

Comment: Marking as answer as agree it doesn't appear to be possible in EF without additional call.